# Armazenar dados de um input no mysql + Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Estou tentando armazenar os dados dos inputs abaixo com javascript porem o mesmo não esta armazenando:

**Arquivo usuers.html**

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">


<input type="button" value="Cadastrar" onclick="clicar()"> <br><br>

<div id="res">Nome</div>

<script>
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'willian',
    password: '123456',
    database: 'celke'

});
</script>
```

Na forma abaixo com a função clicar o mesmo não funciona e nao adiciona os dados no banco.
**Arquivo acessos.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '123456',
    database: 'local'

});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }

    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

connection.connect(function(err, ){
    if(err) console.error('Erro ao realizar a conxeão com BD:', + err.stack); return;
})


function clicar(){
    var  nome = window.document.getElementById('nome').value;
    var email = window.document.getElementById('email').value;

    connection.query("INSERT INTO users(nome, email) VALUES ("+nome+", "+email+")", function(err, result){
        if(!err){
            window.alert('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!');
        }else{
            window('Erro ao cadastrar usuario!');
        }
    }); 
}
```

Porém se eu testo apenas adicionar com o código abaixo sem função pra ver se a conexão do banco esta funcionando, o mesmo adiciona com sucesso:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO users(nome, email) VALUES ('felipe', 'felipe@felipe')", function(err, result){
    if(!err){
        console.log('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!');
    }else{
        console.log('Erro ao cadastrar usuario!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma SQL funciona, a outra não, então basta verificar o que há de diferente entre elas.

A que funciona é:

```
"INSERT INTO users(nome, email) VALUES ('felipe', 'felipe@felipe')"
```

Que há aspas simples nos valores. A que não funciona é:

```
"INSERT INTO users(nome, email) VALUES ("+nome+", "+email+")"
```

Sem as aspas simples, então para corrigir bastaria adicionar as aspas.

Porém, se está utilizando a [`mysqljs/mysql`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), faça, vide documentação:

```js
connection.query("INSERT INTO users(nome, email) VALUES (?, ?)", [nome, email], function(err, result) {
  if (!err) {
    window.alert('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!');
  } else {
    window('Erro ao cadastrar usuario!');
  }
}
```